# in vs on vs with your journey

Tags: prepositions

Graduation day is coming; when trying to send a card to a friend I have a difficulty to decide which preposition to use in this simple phrase.

"Good luck with/in/on your journey!"

My first thought is to use "on". However; a google search shows the three prepositions are often used.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are wanting to say something like *Good luck on your journey through life*. I think, as a native speaker, that *on* would be the best one to use, but there is also nothing especially wrong with either of the other two.

Answer (score 2):

"On your journey" sounds the most natural to me (American native speaker). An [ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20your%20journey%2Cin%20your%20journey%2Cwith%20your%20journey&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20your%20journey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20your%20journey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20your%20journey%3B%2Cc0) shows that "on" is more common than the others.

Comment: Interesting: "Good luck on your journey" sounds slightly unusual to me (Australian native speaker). The expression "on your journey" is normal enough, but I would usually say "good luck _with_ [something]", so the two expressions don't merge easily. To avoid the conflict, I would probably say "Good luck on your trip" or "Good luck with your travels".

Comment: @Chappo: The OP seems to be referring to, not physical (spatial) traveling, but rather the metaphysical journey of life (post-graduation). Does that change your reaction to the phrase?

Comment: @Scott: good point, I'd responded to the literal rather than the metaphysical. ["Again?" I hear my friends shout]. I'd probably say "Good luck **for** the future" or "Good luck **in** your future career", but if forced to stick with _journey_, "Good luck **on** your journey [through life]" sounds fine. Interesting how much difference one word can make to the choice of preposition!